# Spring scheduled work at 21:30 gmt+3

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I'm trying to trigger a method with spring @Scheduled . I thought i should use zone but nothing happens. By the way I'm increasing minute like 30,31,32 for test also tried for gmt+2 and gmt+3.

This is the annotation i try-->

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 21 * * * " , zone="Europe/Moscow")
```

Anyone know why ? Where did i go wrong ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set when the scheduler is to run, but possibly not actually enabled it.

Add `@EnableScheduling` to where you have defined your main Application class.